# Show matrix in thymeleaf html page

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop, thymeleaf

I have to show into a page the values of a matrix. Exactly I have a excel file mapped into matrix (ExcelField[][]) and the first row of this file is the label of the value of the below row (e.g. age heigh sex and th below row has the value 20 170 F).
Now I have to show the value near the label, three or four of this for any row of bootstrap page, like so:

[image]

The problem is the use of the matrix and the number of columns to show for any row. I think that it is impossible to use th:each as above image, it is possible to use for with variable as in java? Is there another way to make this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have written and tested, it works fine:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div th:each="j: ${#numbers.sequence(1, rowSize)}">
            <div th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, colSize)}">
                <div th:if="${i%3==0}">
                    <div class="row"></div>
                </div>
                <h3 th:if="${i==0 or i%3==0}">
                    <span class="label label-primary col-xs-1"
                        th:text="${excelSheet[0][i].value}"></span>
                </h3>
                <h3 th:if="${i!=0 and i%3!=0}">
                    <span class="label label-primary col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1"
                        th:text="${excelSheet[0][i].value}"></span>
                </h3>
                <input class="km col-xs-2" name="distance" type="text"
                    th:value="${excelSheet[j][i].value}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```